# How do I solve this "unexpected '}' syntax error" in my bash script?

Tags: bash, syntax

I have a piece of code that has some serious issues and I was hoping to get it solved soon but no one has offered any help. I thought I'd try some Ubuntu users since this is the OS running the script.

```
mc_addplugin() {
    if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
    then
        echo "$SERVICE is running! Please stop the service before adding a plugin."
    else
        echo "Paste the URL to the .JAR Plugin..."
        read JARURL
        JARNAME=$(basename "$JARURL")
        if [ -d "$TEMPPLUGINS" ]
        then
            as_user "cd $PLUGINSPATH && wget -r -A.jar $JARURL -o temp_plugins/$JARNAME"
        else
            as_user "cd $PLUGINSPATH && mkdir $TEMPPLUGINS && wget -r -A.jar $JARURL -o temp_plugins/$JARNAME"
        fi
    if [ -f "$TMPDIR/$JARNAME" ]
    then
        if [ -f "$PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME" ]
        then
            if `diff $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME $TMPDIR/$JARNAME >/dev/null`
            then 
                echo "You are already running the latest version of $JARNAME."
            else
                NOW=`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%M"`
                echo "Are you sure you want to overwrite this plugin? [Y/n]"
                echo "Note: Your old plugin will be moved to the "$TEMPPLUGINS" folder with todays date."
                select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                    case $yn in
                        Yes ) as_user "mv $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME $TEMPPLUGINS/${JARNAME}_${NOW} && mv $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME"; break;;
                        No ) echo "The plugin has not been installed! Removing temporary plugin and exiting..."
                            as_user "rm $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME"; exit;;
                    esac
                done
                echo "Would you like to start the $SERVICE now? [Y/n]"
                select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                    case $yn in
                        Yes ) mc_start; break;;
                        No ) "$SERVICE not running! To start the service run: /etc/init.d/craftbukkit start"; exit;;
                        esac
                done
            fi
        else
            echo "Are you sure you want to add this new plugin? [Y/n]"
            select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                case $yn in
                    Yes ) as_user "mv $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME $TEMPPLUGINS/${JARNAME}_${NOW} && mv $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME $PLUGINSPATH/$JARNAME"; break;;
                    No ) echo "The plugin has not been installed! Removing temporary plugin and exiting..."
                        as_user "rm $TEMPPLUGINS/$JARNAME"; exit;;
                esac
            done
            echo "Would you like to start the $SERVICE now? [Y/n]?"
            select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                case $yn in
                    Yes ) mc_start; break;;
                    No ) "$SERVICE not running! To start the service run: /etc/init.d/craftbukkit start"; exit;;
                esac
            done
        fi
    else
        echo "Failed to download the plugin from the URL you specified!"
        exit;
    fi
}
```

It throws it at the closing bracket at the end of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `fi` statement to close the first `if`/`then`/`else` conditional.

Comment: Really? I swear I looked. Lol

Comment: @WASasquatch: If this answer solves your problem, please mark it as answered by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.